# Select different values of a column having count more than one

Tags: sql

I have a table like this

```
SA_ID ---+---Acct_Id---+---SA_Type
101           111           TYPE1
102           111           TYPE2
103           112           TYPE1
```

I have a query to get acct_id having more than one sa_type

```
select acct_id,count(*) from sa_tbl
having count(*) > 1
group by acct_id;
```

I get a result like this

```
acct_id ---+---count(*)
111             2
```

But I need to get the result like this:

```
acct_id ---+---count(*)-----+sa_type1----+---sa_type2
    111             2        TYPE1            TYPE2
```

Comment: What purpose will a 'variable column' output serve? If you want more complex outputs like this, try creating a Procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to get result like you mentioned in question but able to get something similar to this 
check it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a54af4/1)

```
SELECT tbl.`Acct_Id` AS 'Acct_Id',COUNT(`Acct_Id`)  AS 'counts',
GROUP_CONCAT(`SA_Type`) AS 'types'
FROM `sa_tbl` AS tbl 
GROUP BY tbl.`Acct_Id` 
HAVING counts > 1
```

hope this will help you !

Answer (score 0):

Check the pivot function, see question here [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

This function works for Oracle and MySQL. For other databases (if you need) you can check additionally by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If your RDBMS doesn't support PIVOT (as was already suggested to you), you can use a combination of MAX / CASE / GROUP BY:

```
select 
  acct_id,
  max((case when sa_type = 'TYPE1' then sa_id else NULL end)) as type1,
  max((case when sa_type = 'TYPE2' then sa_id else NULL end)) as type2
from sa_tbl
group by acct_id
```

Output:

```
acct_id type1   type2
112     103 
111     101     102
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ef3fb/1)